# How to set a background of WPF Window?

Tags: wpf, background

I have a simple WPF window. I intend to set it's background to be one of the images I added to project as Embedded Resource. This is what I tried:

```
<Window x:Class="A_Boggle.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="A-Boggle" Height="300" Width="625" ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" Name="Game">
<Window.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="background.jpg"></ImageBrush>
</Window.Background>
<Grid>
</Grid>
```

But with this, i always get this: "Error 1 The file splash.jpg is not part of the project or its 'Build Action' property is not set to 'Resource'."

Any ideas?

Answer (score 21):

Go to the image within VS and set the item to be a Resource. Right click -> Properties -> Build Action -> Resource

**Update:**

You need to change the path if it is in a folder. ie...Resources/background.jpg

Comment: Right. Note that 'Resource' is different than 'Embedded Resource'.

Comment: Still not working, getting the same error. Does it matter that image is in Resources folder?

Comment: Tried this, and I get the error  ´Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\Images\marmor_hintergrund_weiss.png'.´ Any idea how to get my xaml to look within my project folder and not the IDEs folder?

Comment: Something sitting inside "Program File" might run into permission or access issue.

Answer (score 4):

**you can use this in main.xaml.cs**

```
  InitializeComponent();
        ImageBrush myBrush = new ImageBrush();
        myBrush.ImageSource =
            new BitmapImage(new Uri("F://13.png", UriKind.Absolute));
        this.Background = myBrush;
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue in my case was becouse i set the Heigth and width properties on the window and use maximized windows state , when i remove the width and heigth properties the error dissapear.